# Structuring forms and inputs to facilitate iteration using fieldset-only IDs

Tags: jquery, input, fieldset

Let's say that I have 3 fieldsets, each with 2 inputs: NAME and AGE.
Later, I want to iterate over the forms with JQUERY and read all of the inputs for each fieldset.

How should I structure the fieldsets and inputs to best facilitate the iteration?  Right now, I'm assigning unique IDs to each input - but if possible, it would be better to push the unique identifier further up the tree to something like the fieldset tag.

How would I be able to use Jquery to access each element in the collection of fieldset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this,
Assign 'name' class for each name textboxes and 'age' class for all age textBoxes. And then iterate through the each feildset like tihs,

```
var people=[];
$('feildset').each(function(index,feildset){
    people.push({Name:$('.name',feildset).val(), Age:$('.age',feildset).val()})
});
```

Comment: I used this idea. But instead of assigning a class, i used the input's name like so: $('[name="age"]',fieldset).val().

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset id="fieldset_1">
  <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="text" class="age">
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="fieldset_2">
  <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="text" class="age">
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="fieldset_3">
  <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="text" class="age">
</fieldset>
```

Then you could:

```
$("fieldset").each(function(){
  alert($(this).id + " has the name value: " + $(this).find("input.name").val());
  alert($(this).id + " has the age value: " + $(this).find("input.age").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('fieldset').each(function() {
   var cls = $(this).attr('id');
   // this makes a ul element with a class based on the fieldset's id and appends it to the body
   $('</ul>').text($(this).attr('id') + ':').addClass(cls).appendTo('body');
   $(this).find('input').each(function() { // iterating over fieldset's inputs
       // this adds list elements to the ul 
       $('</li>').text($(this).attr('name') + ': ' + $(this).val()).appendTo("." + cls);
   })
})
```

Comment: What if they're further down the DOM than children? Also, `.children('input')` would be more efficient if you have generic, non-`ID` selectors like that.